# Webservice using keycloak with policy enforcement returning empty body for a specific endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a springboot webservice that is using Keycloak for authorization & authentication. In my Keycloak config,  I have enabled Authorization, and I have the Default Resource, which has the default permission to allow all the users. In webservice, I have multiple endpoints, each one configured with their own policy-enforcer config. The config in application.properties looks like this:

```
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=*
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/*

keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=permissive
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.lazy-load-paths=true

keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].name=project
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].path=/projects/{projectId}
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].claimInformationPointConfig.project[claim-value]=claim
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].enforcement-mode=permissive
```

I have a ClaimInformationPointProviderFactory and a permission provider defined such that any request coming to the /projects/{projectId} goes thru the permission provider where I can do some custom access control checking. The problem I am facing is that I have some end-points on which I don't want any authentication i.e. they should proceed without any bearer token provided.

I have tried defining a policy enforcer config for the unauthenticated paths in application.properties where enforcement is disabled as follows:

```
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[1].name=unauth
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[1].path=/unauth/{id}
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[1].claimInformationPointConfig.unauth[claim-value]=unauthtuff
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[1].enforcement-mode=disabled
```

I have also defined a bean for the WebSecurity where I allow the /unauth/** paths to go thru as follows:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/unauth/**").permitAll()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();;
     return http.build();
}
```

With a combination of the enforcer config and the bean, any requests made returns me an HTTP 200 code but the endpoint doesn't actually get hit, and no content in the response body is being returned. Using either one of the enforcer config and the bean on their own gives 403 for all the calls to unauth path. If a bearer token however is provided, the endpoint does get hit and the response contains the required content, so I am suspecting that there is some missing spring config that I need to add. Been stuck on this for a few days, would greatly appreciate if anyone can help out with this.

Comment: The Keycloak adapters you are using were deprecated more than a year ago and are not even compatible with Spring Boot 3 / Security 6. Also, you should think twice before using policy enforcer which is very specific to Keycloak and has many other drawbacks (hardly unit-testable, easy to get discrepancies between environments, possible to insert bogus / malicious rules in prod, etc.)

Comment: As an alternative for access control, use Spring Security. Refer to [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials). Some of it implement quite advanced access rules (based on user roles, accessed resource itself and more)

Comment: The reason I am using policy enforcers is that the permission matrix of which users have access to which projects is stored in Redis. The users in the system don't have a hard role of Project Members. They might be member in 1 project and not a member in another. With the policy-enforcer, I can build claims of the permission matrix and let Keycloak's Javascript check the claims and return whether the user is authorized for the call, based on if they are a member of the project.

Comment: Or you expose this matrix of roles per project for a given user on a web service and write a keycloak mapper to include it in access tokens. I have done something like that in the `resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication` tutorial and in [this other project](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies) (Keycloak mapper source code only in the later).

Comment: I thought of that but this matrix can be quite big. I do have other entities other than project and including the entire thing in the access token would not be possible because of token's and URLs size constraints

Comment: If the data required as access control rules input for a given user with a given client (this is what a token is issued for) doesn't fit in a JWT, it is very likely that people in charge of setting this data won't grasp it correctly. In such a situation, I'd probably put energy in finding a way to simplify access control rules input...